# Cant change the if statement from with in a case switch statement

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, switch-statement

Im trying to change the value of an int used in a if statement from inside the if statement in a switch statement however i cant work out how to change the value with out making a new instance of the variable.

The class where the issue is, is in the main class the rest of the classes are needed for the code but arnt to relevant. The FramePanel Class however initializes the decisionChooser method when the user enters a number into the gui command box.

Below is my full code. Under the main class is where you will find the if and switch statements in question:

Main Class:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FramePanel.runLater();
        StoryArray.main();
    }

    public int a1;
    public int a2;
    public int a3;
    public int a4;
    public int a5;
    public int textNumber;
    public String chosenText;


    public void decisionChooser()
    {
        String inputText = FramePanel.commandsField.getText();
        FramePanel.commandsField.setText(null);
        try
        {
            textNumber = Integer.parseInt(inputText);
            textNumber = textNumber - 1;

            if (textNumber == a1 || textNumber == a2 || textNumber == a3 || textNumber == a4 || textNumber == a5)
            {
                System.out.println(textNumber + " in If");

                System.out.println("Entering switch");
                switch (textNumber)
                {
                    case 0:
                        a1 = 70; // this will change a1 for in the if statement
                        chosenText = StoryArray.storyLine[textNumber];
                        FramePanel.currentTextArea.append(chosenText + "\n");
                        break;

                    case 70:
                        a1 = 281;
                        chosenText = StoryArray.storyLine[textNumber];
                        FramePanel.currentTextArea.append(chosenText + "\n");
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                FramePanel.currentTextArea.append("\nPlease choose a valid page number!\n");
            }
            System.out.println("Out of If statement");
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException NFE)
        {
            FramePanel.currentTextArea.append("Please Enter the Page number" + "\n");
        }
        System.out.println("looped");
    }
}
```

FramePanel Class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FramePanel extends JPanel
{
    /////Setting Positioning/////

    // rows and cols for jtextarea
    private static final int CURRENT_AREA_ROWS = 20;
    private static final int CURRENT_AREA_COLS = 40;

    // columns for command jtextfied
    private static final int COMMANDS_FIELD_COLS = 50;

    // size of GUI component gaps
    private static final int EB_GAP = 1;

    private String inventoryString()
    {
        return ("Inventory:" +
                "\n- " +
                "\n- " +
                "\n- " +
                "\n- " +
                "\n- " +
                "\n- " +
                "\n- " +
                "\n- " +
                "\n- " +
                "\n- ");
    }

    private String startString()
    {
        return ("Welcome to Warlock of Firetop Mountain! This game was coded by Thomas Thorburn and the story line was written by Ian Livingstone and Steve Jackson. To get started, click 'New Game' or load a save. If you get stuck click the 'Help' button or read the 'Help and Information' document.\n\nLet the Adventure Begin!");
    }
    private EnterAction enterAction = new EnterAction("Enter");

    public static JTextArea currentTextArea = new JTextArea(CURRENT_AREA_ROWS, CURRENT_AREA_COLS);
    public static JTextField commandsField = new JTextField(COMMANDS_FIELD_COLS);
    public static JTextArea inventoryTextArea = new JTextArea(CURRENT_AREA_ROWS, CURRENT_AREA_COLS);



    public FramePanel()
    {

        JPanel topBtnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        {
            topBtnPanel.add(new JButton(new HelpAction("Help", KeyEvent.VK_X)));
            topBtnPanel.add(new JButton(new RollAction("Roll Dice", KeyEvent.VK_X)));
            topBtnPanel.add(new JButton(new NewGameAction("New Game", KeyEvent.VK_X)));
            topBtnPanel.add(new JButton(new SaveAction("Save", KeyEvent.VK_X)));
            topBtnPanel.add(new JButton(new LoadAction("Load", KeyEvent.VK_X)));
        }

        JPanel characteristicsPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        {
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            characteristicsPanel.add(new JTextField("20"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy ++;
            characteristicsPanel.add(new JTextField("20"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy ++;
            characteristicsPanel.add(new JTextField("20"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy ++;
            characteristicsPanel.add(new JTextField("20"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy ++;
            characteristicsPanel.add(new JTextField("20"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy ++;
            characteristicsPanel.add(new JTextField("20"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy ++;
            characteristicsPanel.add(new JTextField("20"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy ++;

            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            characteristicsPanel.add(new JLabel("SKILL:  "), gbc);
            gbc.gridy ++;
            characteristicsPanel.add(new JLabel("STAMINA:  "), gbc);
            gbc.gridy ++;
            characteristicsPanel.add(new JLabel("LUCK:  "), gbc);
            gbc.gridy ++;
            characteristicsPanel.add(new JLabel("GOLD:  "), gbc);
            gbc.gridy ++;
            characteristicsPanel.add(new JLabel("JEWELS:  "), gbc);
            gbc.gridy ++;
            characteristicsPanel.add(new JLabel("POTIONS:  "), gbc);
            gbc.gridy ++;
            characteristicsPanel.add(new JLabel("PREVISIONS:  "), gbc);
            gbc.gridy ++;
        }

        inventoryTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        inventoryTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
        inventoryTextArea.setEditable(true);
        inventoryTextArea.append(inventoryString());
        JScrollPane imgListPane = new JScrollPane(inventoryTextArea);
        imgListPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(EB_GAP, EB_GAP));
        rightPanel.add(topBtnPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        rightPanel.add(imgListPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        rightPanel.add(characteristicsPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

        currentTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        currentTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
        currentTextArea.setFocusable(false);
        currentTextArea.append(startString());
        JScrollPane taScrollPane = new JScrollPane(currentTextArea);
        taScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        centerPanel.add(taScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        centerPanel.add(rightPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

        JPanel commandsPanel = new JPanel();
        commandsPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(commandsPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        commandsPanel.add(commandsField);
        commandsPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(EB_GAP));
        commandsPanel.add(new JButton(enterAction));
        commandsPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(EB_GAP));
        commandsField.setAction(enterAction); // use same action for button and


        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(EB_GAP, EB_GAP, EB_GAP, EB_GAP));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(EB_GAP, EB_GAP));
        add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(commandsPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }


    /////////Buttons/////////
    //Enter Button Action
    private class EnterAction extends AbstractAction
    {
        public EnterAction(String name)
        {
            super(name);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            Main mainChoices = new Main();//Allowing me to call Main
            mainChoices.decisionChooser();//Calling up decisionChooser method
        }
    }

    //Help Action
    private class HelpAction extends AbstractAction
    {
        public HelpAction (String name, int mnemonic)
        {
            super(name);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            currentTextArea.append("\n\n" + "Welcome to Warlock of Firetop Mountain! To navigate the story line just enter the relevant page number in the text box below, To make this game as authentic as possiable to the original game, all combat stats and inventory are controlled by the user. \n\nTo Save, Load or start a New Game, use the corresponding buttons in the top right of the window. To roll the dice you also click the 'Roll Dice' button. This will print the two dice rolls in your storyline box. For more information, please refer to the help and information guide provided with this program." + "\n \n");
        }
    }

    //New Game Button and Action
    private class NewGameAction extends AbstractAction
    {
        public NewGameAction (String name, int mnemonic)
        {
            super(name);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            currentTextArea.setText(startString());
        }
    }

    //Load Button and Action
    private class LoadAction extends AbstractAction
    {
        public LoadAction (String name, int mnemonic)
        {
            super(name);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            OpenFile of = new OpenFile();

            try
            {
                of.PickMe();
            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            currentTextArea.setText(of.sb.toString());
        }
    }

    //Save Button and Action
    private class SaveAction extends AbstractAction
    {
        public SaveAction (String name, int mnemonic)
        {
            super(name);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.out.print("yo3");
        }
    }

    //Exit Button and Action
    private class ExitAction extends AbstractAction
    {
        public ExitAction(String name, int mnemonic)
        {
            super(name);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            Component source = (Component) e.getSource();
            Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(source);
            win.dispose();
        }
    }

    //Roll Button Action
    private class RollAction extends AbstractAction
    {
        public RollAction(String name, int mnemonic)
        {
            super(name);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            Random r = new Random();

            int diceRoll1=r.nextInt(6); //Generates random number
            int diceRoll2=r.nextInt(6);


            diceRoll1 = diceRoll1 + 1; //Changes range from 0-5 to 1-6
            diceRoll2 = diceRoll2 + 1;

            currentTextArea.append("You have rolled a " + diceRoll1 + " and a " + diceRoll2 + "!" + "\n");
        }
    }


    /////////GUI Setup/////////
    //Making and choosing settings for frame.
    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        FramePanel mainPanel = new FramePanel();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Warlock of Firetop Mountain");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    /////////Getters and Setters/////////
    //Getter for currentTextArea
    public static JTextArea getTextArea()
    {
        return currentTextArea;
    }


    /////////Run Later/////////
    public static void runLater()
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

OpenFile Class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OpenFile
{
    JFileChooser loadFile = new JFileChooser();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    public void PickMe() throws Exception
    {
        if(loadFile.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            java.io.File file = loadFile.getSelectedFile();


            Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

            while (input.hasNext())
            {
                sb.append(input.nextLine());
                sb.append("\n\n");
            }
            input.close();

        }
        else
        {
            sb.append("\n\n" + "No File Selected! \n\n");

        }
    }
}
```

StoryArray Class(Shortened because amount of strings):

```
public class StoryArray
{
    public static String storyLine[] = null ;
    public static String[] getStoryLine()
    {
        return storyLine;
    }
    public static void main()
    {
        //String[] storyLine;
        storyLine = new String[399];
        storyLine[0] = ("test1");
        storyLine[1] = ("test2");
        storyLine[2] = ("test 3");
        storyLine[18] = ("test4");

        storyLine[69] = ("Test5");
        storyLine[70] = ("Test6");
        storyLine[71] = ("Test7");
        storyLine[73] = ("Test8");
    }
}
```

Comment: Which variable are you trying to change?

Comment: Please describe the expected behavior of your code and what is happening instead.

Comment: Oh sorry i didnt realise id accidently removed something when testing i will edit the code quickly, what i want to happen is have a statement in the case 0: or 70 which will change the value of a1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 for the next time the if statement is run

Comment: @TomT you don't have the right to delete/open the same question over and over. Previous: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36178731/changing-int-from-inside-a-switch-statement

Comment: apologies, i deleted it to start again with a better structured question as the last caused confusion and by starting a fresh i could make sure i included the stuff needed

Comment: edit and restructure, that's the way to do it.

Comment: ok, in future i will, sorry i didnt realise it was an issue

Comment: This could be a thread problem.  What behavior are you seeing?  You are setting up the StoryArray class in a different thread from the thread that uses that class.  There's no guarantee that the one thread will see those changes.

Comment: My terminology isn't the best so I'm not sure how two answer but when i call up "StoryArray.main();" that is just for being able to append the string to a JTextArea. The issue lies with the if statement in the main class under the decision chooser method. What i want to happen is when the if statement runs which then starts my switch statement i want there to be new value for the if statement "if (textNumber == a1)" in this case a1 to be changed in the case statement by having a1 = 70 for example which will update the value used in the if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that making a variable public doesn't make it a class variable. This meant each time I ran the loop it would create a new instance of the variable. To change this and make it a class variable, I had to declare it as static, this meant that there could only be one instance, so each time I ran the loop and changed the values in the switch statement it would change the values outside the loop as well.

This is how i had to declare it:

```
public static int textNumber;
```